# How can i get XML data from the dictionary

Tags: php, xml

Below is `XML format`:

```
    <item>
                <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
                <link>http://www.website.com</link>
                <pubDate>Sun, 30 Aug 2015 16:51:18 +0000</pubDate>
                <description>
                    <![CDATA[Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text]]>
                </description>

                <title>Lorem ipsum test</title>
                <link>http://www.test.com</link>
                <pubDate>Sun, 29 Aug 2015 16:51:18 +0000</pubDate>
                <description>
                    <![CDATA[Dummy text test Dummy text test Dummy text test]]>
                </description>
    </item>
```

What i have tried:

```
    <?php
    $rss = file_get_contents('<URL>');
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($rss);
    foreach($xml->channel->item as $feed){
        $title = $feed->title;
        $added_date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date));
        $description = $feed->description;
        print_r($title);
        print_r($description);
    }
    ?>
```

it is giving me this output for **description**:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )
```

How can i get **description** data?

Comment: Did you try any code that we can help you on fixing?

Comment: yes.. of course i tried after that i asked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try php:s SimpleXML: Load your XML, then access the element

```
$items = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);
echo $items->description;
```

EDIT: ok, i see that you have changed your XML in the question now, but the solution should still work. The code echoes "dymmy..." on this sandbox too: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ Something in your description is missing, or you are running a strange system. You can alternatively try this loading of the sring (should convert cadata objects to clean strings)

```
$items = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

Further, you can try to cast the element you are getting to a strin:

```
echo (string) $items->description;
```

Comment: i have already tried this and it is giving me this: SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)

Comment: Your solution will work if it is like: `<description>dummy text</description>`

Comment: what version of php are you running? Im getting "Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text" as the output

Comment: XML data are from URL. so it is in this form what i have wrote in my question

Comment: Thank you.. `echo (string) $items->description;` is working.